# django query for select unique rows based on foreign key field value

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Hi I have two models like this

```html
class Department(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  creator = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  description = models.TextField()
  is_active= models.BooleanField(default=True)
  department = models.ForeignKey(Deparment)
  post_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Users can create n number of posts from the same department n number of times.
But I want to fetch only one post from each department .for ex:
department A has 10 users, all users are posted with same title and description
Department B has 10 users, all users are posted with the same title and description.

now I want to fetch first created post from each department, in my results I want first created post from department A and first created Post from department B.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First get all the **departments** and then get first_post from every department:

```
departments = Department.objects.all()

post_list = []

for department in departments:
    post_list.append(department.post_set.all()[0])
```

Now the `post_list` will have one post from every department.